# What data validation we must use in different contexts?

Tags: code, validation

Recently, my theme got rejected on Themeforest and one of the rejection issue is:

> Data Validation issues have been found in your theme. All dynamic data
>   must be correctly escaped for the context where it is rendered.
>   Please perform a global search for echo $ and you will see several
>   issues.

Since I use different contexts where I use `echo $` I'm a bit confused how to solve all this. Here are some examples:

One:

```
echo $options_machine->Menu
```

Two:

```
<input type="hidden" id="reset" value="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['reset'])) echo $_REQUEST['reset']; ?>" />
```

Three:

```
        function optionsframework_activation_notice() {

        if ( isset( $_GET['activated'] ) ) {

            $output = '<div class="updated activation"><p><strong>';
            $my_theme = wp_get_theme();
            $output .= sprintf( __( '%s activated successfully!', 'matilda' ), $my_theme->get( 'Name' ) );
            $output .= '</strong> <a target="_blank" href="' . home_url( '/' ) . '">' . __( 'Visit Site', 'matilda' ) . '</a></p>';
            $output .= ' <a class="button button-primary td-activation" href="' . admin_url( 'themes.php?page=matilda_panel' ) . '">' . __( 'Theme Options', 'matilda' ) . '</a>';
            $output .= ' <a class="button button-primary td-activation" href="' . admin_url( 'widgets.php' ) . '">' . __( 'Widgets Settings', 'matilda' ) . '</a>';
            $output .= ' <a class="button button-primary td-activation" target="_blank" href="http://google.com/">' . __( 'Support', 'matilda' ) . '</a>';
            $output .= ' <a class="button button-primary td-activation" target="_blank" href="http://google.com">' . __( 'Documentation', 'matilda' ) . '</a>';
            $output .= '</p></div>';

            echo $output;

        }

    }
```

How to correctly escape this **echo $** in these contexts?

Comment: Close voting as too broad. The type of validation, sanitation and escaping depends on the context of the data and type of data you are expecting from a particular variable/field/URL etc. You should take your time and read through [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)

Comment: Just to add, what you have posted is only the tip of the iceberg. If you are not sure about anything, you should consider hiring a pro of contact the themeforest team with specific issues

Comment: @PieterGoosen a solution for every these three examples will save my day, please!